# the following packages is nedded for installing audacity in fedora linux redhat 6

Tags: fedora, package-management, yum, rpm

I want to install audacity in my machine (red hat 6 fedora), when I try to install the following error shows. How to fix this?

```
flac-devel is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
jack-audio-connection-kit-devel is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
ladspa-devel is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
libid3tag-devel is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
taglib-devel is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
libogg-devel is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
libsndfile-devel is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
libvorbis-devel is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
portaudio-devel >= 19-16 is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
soundtouch-devel is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
soxr-devel is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
vamp-plugin-sdk-devel >= 2.0 is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
wxGTK-devel is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
libappstream-glib is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you download RPM package and using `rpm -i <rpm packge>.rpm` to install

Actually you can install audacity with `yum install audacity`,   yum will resolve the package dependence for you